# How to count the frequency of occurrence from multiple response (i.e. "check all that apply") questions? - Python

Tags: python

I'm completely new to coding and analysis, but I'm trying to use Python to analyze some data (and having a lot of fun learning it :D )

***Example Data:***
Asking people who they live with. If they do live with those people then it's marked as "1'.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1]], columns=["Family", "Relatives", "Friends", "Others"])
```

*Data*

```
|   | Family | Relatives | Friends | Others |
| - | ------ | --------- | ------- | ------ |
| 0 | 0      | 1         | 0       | 0      |
| 1 | 0      | 1         | 1       | 1      |
| 2 | 0      | 1         | 0       | 0      |
| 3 | 0      | 0         | 1       | 1      |
```

***What I Want to Know:*** The frequency of the combinations that occur.

For example, how often does a person live with just their family? Or how often does a person live with both friends and relatives, etc.?

*Expected Results*

```
RELATIONSHIP TYPE        FREQUENCY OF OCCURRENCE
Family (Only)              - 0
Relatives (Only)           - 2
Relatives, Friends, Others - 1
Friends, Others            - 1
```

I haven't been really able to try anything since I can't even figure out the functions I can use. So any insight would be really helpful! Thank you!

Comment: try ```df.plot.hist()``` and see the output

Comment: I think `Relatives` is 3 rather than 2 and `Friends, Others` is 2 rather than 1. Are they typo?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh ah I should have specified "Only Friends" and "Only Relatives". I'll go ahead and edit the question. Thanks noting!

Comment: @raviolibanana See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use `df.values.tolist()` to convert dataframe to a list of row value list.

Then you can use [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the occurrence of each row value list.

```py
from collections import Counter

data = []

for k, v in Counter(tuple(row) for row in df.values.tolist()).items():
    data.append([', '.join([df.columns[i] for i, x in enumerate(list(k)) if x]), v])

frequency = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['RELATIONSHIP TYPE', 'FREQUENCY OF OCCURRENCE'])
```

```
# print(frequency)

            RELATIONSHIP TYPE  FREQUENCY OF OCCURRENCE
0                   Relatives                        2
1  Relatives, Friends, Others                        1
2             Friends, Others                        1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['Family','Relatives','Friends','Others']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

outputs

```
   Family  Relatives  Friends  Others  count
0       0          0        1       1      1
1       0          1        0       0      2
2       0          1        1       1      1
```

so all the permutations you're interested in, i.e. just relatives occurs twice.